# WCF Web Service Response XML file

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am using a data contract in WCF, but there is some unwanted response tags being sent in the xml file, I am not sure how to modify the data contract class so that I can avoid sending that unwanted response field. In the below XML file, all the text which is bolded and italics is unwanted. Thanks.

```
  <GetCertMailReceiptNumbersResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetCertMailReceiptNumbersResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfSmartConnect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        ***<a:AccountNumber i:nil="true" />
        <a:Address1 i:nil="true" />
        <a:Address2 i:nil="true" />
        <a:City i:nil="true" />
        <a:Name1 i:nil="true" />
        <a:Name2 i:nil="true" />
        <a:OrderNumber>1325661</a:OrderNumber>
        <a:Password i:nil="true" />***
        <a:ReturnCode>200</a:ReturnCode>
        <a:ReturnMessage />
        ***<a:SoftwareID i:nil="true" />
        <a:State i:nil="true" />
        <a:TrackingStatus i:nil="true" />
        <a:USPSReceipt i:nil="true" />
        <a:UserID i:nil="true" />
        <a:Zip i:nil="true" />***
        <a:lsCMRN>
          <a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
            <a:AccountNumber>1</a:AccountNumber>
            <a:Address1>201 Test Ln</a:Address1>
            <a:Address2>TSTCity TST  123456</a:Address2>
            <a:City>TSTCity</a:City>
            <a:Name1>pinu</a:Name1>
            <a:Name2 i:nil="true" />
            <a:OrderNumber />
            ***<a:Password />
            <a:ReturnCode>0</a:ReturnCode>
            <a:ReturnMessage i:nil="true" />
            <a:SoftwareID />***
            <a:State> TST </a:State>
            <a:TrackingStatus>MAILED</a:TrackingStatus>
            <a:USPSReceipt>71926389001019</a:USPSReceipt>
            ***<a:UserID />***
            <a:Zip>123456</a:Zip>
            <a:lsCMRN />
            <a:order>1325661</a:order>
          </a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
          <a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
            <a:AccountNumber>10</a:AccountNumber>
            <a:Address1>121 Mant Drive</a:Address1>
            <a:Address2>TestCity  Test  123456</a:Address2>
            <a:City> TestCity </a:City>
            <a:Name1>Kris </a:Name1>
            <a:Name2 i:nil="true" />
            <a:OrderNumber />
            ***<a:Password />
            <a:ReturnCode>0</a:ReturnCode>
            <a:ReturnMessage i:nil="true" />
            <a:SoftwareID />***
            <a:State>Test</a:State>
            <a:TrackingStatus>MAILED</a:TrackingStatus>
            <a:USPSReceipt>71926389000026</a:USPSReceipt>
            ***<a:UserID />***
            <a:Zip>123456</</a:Zip>
            <a:lsCMRN />
            <a:order>1325661</a:order>
          </a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
          <a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
            <a:AccountNumber>2</a:AccountNumber>
            <a:Address1>121 Technot</a:Address1>
            <a:Address2>Test  Tst  123456</a:Address2>
            <a:City>Test</a:City>
            <a:Name1>Alice</a:Name1>
            <a:Name2 i:nil="true" />
            <a:OrderNumber />
            ***<a:Password />
            <a:ReturnCode>0</a:ReturnCode>
            <a:ReturnMessage i:nil="true" />
            <a:SoftwareID />***
            <a:State>Tst</a:State>
            <a:TrackingStatus>MAILED</a:TrackingStatus>
            <a:USPSReceipt>7192638900000033</a:USPSReceipt>
            ***<a:UserID />***
            <a:Zip>123456</</a:Zip>
            <a:lsCMRN />
            <a:order>1325661</a:order>
          </a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
          <a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
            <a:AccountNumber>3</a:AccountNumber>
            <a:Address1>194 Green st</a:Address1>
            <a:Address2>Matt  MA  123456</a:Address2>
            <a:City>Matt</a:City>
            <a:Name1>Jewel Bondurant</a:Name1>
            <a:Name2 i:nil="true" />
            <a:OrderNumber />
            ***<a:Password />
            <a:ReturnCode>0</a:ReturnCode>
            <a:ReturnMessage i:nil="true" />
            <a:SoftwareID />***
            <a:State>MA</a:State>
            <a:TrackingStatus>MAILED</a:TrackingStatus>
            <a:USPSReceipt>71926389001000000040</a:USPSReceipt>
            ***<a:UserID />***
            <a:Zip>123456</</a:Zip>
            <a:lsCMRN />
            <a:order>1325661</a:order>
          </a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
          <a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
            <a:AccountNumber>4</a:AccountNumber>
            <a:Address1>123  Nasas</a:Address1>
            <a:Address2>Mtar  Tst  123456</a:Address2>
            <a:City>Mtar</a:City>
            <a:Name1>Terry </a:Name1>
            <a:Name2 i:nil="true" />
            ***<a:OrderNumber />
            <a:Password />
            <a:ReturnCode>0</a:ReturnCode>
            <a:ReturnMessage i:nil="true" />
            <a:SoftwareID />***
            <a:State>Tst</a:State>
            <a:TrackingStatus>MAILED</a:TrackingStatus>
           a:USPSReceipt>7192630000057</a:USPSReceipt>
            ***<a:UserID />***
            <a:Zip>123456</</a:Zip>
            <a:lsCMRN />
            <a:order>1325661</a:order>
          </a:CertMailReceiptNumbers>
        </a:lsCMRN>
        <a:order>0</a:order>
      </GetCertMailReceiptNumbersResult>
    </GetCertMailReceiptNumbersResponse>
```

Comment: if you post XML - you need to highlight the lines in question, and press the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar! Otherwise the XML will not be legible and visible....

Comment: show us your class that is being sent back as response!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show us your classes that are being sent back as response from your WCF service! Without them, it's at best a guessing game....

You can put certain DataContract-related attributes on properties to include or exclude them from the serialization process in WCF.

Basically, with WCF in .NET 3.5 SP1, you don't *have to* specifically label your classes and their properties with special attributes anymore. If you don't, the DataContract serializer will act like the XML serializer : all public properties are being serialized.

If you don't want to include certain properties in the serialization, you don't really have a choice but to

- put the `[DataContract]` attribute on your classes, and
- put the `[DataMember]` attribute on your fields and properties that you do want to be serialized

Anything you do not adorn with a [DataMember] attribute will then be skipped and not included in the WCF response message.

So in your case, you would have to do something like

```
[DataContract]
class GetCertMailReceiptNumbersResult
{
    // no DataMember attribute --> will not be included!
    int AccountNumber {get;set;}
    string Address1 {get;set;}
   ......
    string Password {get;set;}

    // here, include DataMember attributes --> will be included
    [DataMember]
    int ReturnCode {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    string ReturnMessage {get;set;}

    // and so forth
 }
```

Basically, for each type in your WCF service, you need to make a decision which fields and properties to include - mark those with the `[DataMember]` attribute. Anything else will *not* be included in your serialized message.

Comment: Hey Marc, 

Thank for letting me know on how to edit xml , I am relatively new to Stack overflow so could not figure out. I have my data contract and the datamemeber's , I just wanted to know if there is some way in which the client will be able to know what is request and what is the response.